java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in PySpark when writing to Parquet file on Windows
I have written the following code:
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import re
import os

os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = 'D:\\hadoop'
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'], 'bin')
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = '(...entire path...)\\python.exe'
def clean_text(text):
    text = text.strip('"')
    text = text.replace('""', '"')
    text = text.replace("\\n", "\n")
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
    return text
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "file:///") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.hadoop.tmp.dir", "file:/D:/hadoop/tmp") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark_df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', inferSchema=True, header=False)
df_schema = ["A", "B", "D"]
spark_df = spark_df.toDF(*df_schema)
clean_text_udf = udf(clean_text, StringType())
spark_df = spark_df.dropna()
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("C", clean_text_udf(col("D")))
spark_df = spark_df.drop("D")
spark_df.write.parquet('D:\\preprocessed_Dataset.parquet', mode='overwrite')

I have downloaded Hadoop binary package (version 3.4.0) from the link https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html and 'winutils.exe' from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/winutils.exe and then have placed this 'winutils.exe' inside D:\hadoop\bin.
Also I have updated the content of 'hdfs-site.xml' as follows:
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/D:/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/D:/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

and also updated the content of 'core-site.xml' as,
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>file:///</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/D:/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

Also I have created folders tmp, data\datanode and data\namenode in D:\hadoop and also all the Environment Variables are correctly set.
My spark version is 3.5.1 and I am using PyCharm IDE
But still I am getting error:
spark_df.write.parquet('D:\\preprocessed_Dataset.parquet', mode='overwrite')
  in parquet
    self._jwrite.parquet(path)
  in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.parquet.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)...

Please help on this
